# what is the format of pagingstate (as string) in Datastax

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

For my unit test, I need to create a dummy `PagingState` value.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/PagingState.html

I can see that there is a `fromString` method which can create the `PagingState` object for me. But I need to provide the string in correct format.

What is the format of `PagingState` ?

I read that `The paging state is a array of 16 bytes`. I tried doing the following

```
val pagingStateByteArray = Array[Byte](1.toByte,2.toByte,3.toByte,4.toByte,5.toByte,6.toByte,7.toByte,8.toByte,9.toByte,10.toByte,11.toByte,12.toByte,13.toByte,14.toByte,15.toByte,16.toByte)
  val pagingState = PagingState.fromBytes(pagingStateByteArray) //make this more accurate. instance of PagingState
```

but got error

```
Cannot deserialize paging state, invalid format. The serialized form was corrupted, or not initially generated from a PagingState object.
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.PagingStateException: Cannot deserialize paging state, invalid format. The serialized form was corrupted, or not initially generated from a PagingState object.
    at com.datastax.driver.core.PagingState.<init>(PagingState.java:60)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.PagingState.fromBytes(PagingState.java:170)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paging state has a meaning for driver ([source code](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/PagingState.java#L56)), so you need to provide meaningful values.

But for your test you can use the same value that is used in the [Java driver tests](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/test/java/com/datastax/driver/core/PagingStateTest.java#L243):

```
PagingState emptyStatement = PagingState.fromString("00000000");;
```

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering why `fromBytes` didn't work for me. Would you know? `val pagingStateByteArray = Array[Byte](1.toByte,2.toByte,3.toByte,4.toByte,5.toByte,6.toByte,7.toByte,8.toByte,9.toByte,10.toByte,11.toByte,12.toByte,13.toByte,14.toByte,15.toByte,16.toByte);
  val pagingState = PagingState.fromBytes(pagingStateByteArray)`. I get `Cannot deserialize paging state,` error if I use `fromBytes`.

Comment: this happens because `PagingState` class is trying to decode data based on provided by you - it is trying to extract different sizes, etc. See source code: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/PagingState.java#L56